# Reversible and Internally reversible

Tags: thermodynamics, reversibility

I know that we cannot plot irreversible process on thermodynamic coordinates....So can we plot 'completely reversible' or just 'Internally reversible' process on thermodynamic coordinates ?

Answer (score 0):

Copmpletely reversible refers to each part of a combined system undergoing an internally reversible process.  So, if the combined system is undergoing a reversible process, each sub-system undergoes an internally reversible process.  For each subsystem, you can plot the path in thermodynamic coordinates.  But, different parts of the combined system undergo different internally reversible paths.  For example an ideal reservoir receives heat reversibly from a cylinder and piston, while the cylinder and piston does work and gives off the heat to the reservoir.  So, since "completely reversible" includes both subsystems, there is no one single path and set of thermodynamic coordinates that characterizes the combination.

Comment: I do not understand this distinction between internal reversible and otherwise reversible process. To me a process is either reversible or it is not, and if it is reversible it must be reversible everywhere. By definition all processes of a heat reservoir is reversible because *its* entropy exchange is exactly $\frac {\delta Q}{T}$ where ${\delta Q}$ is the heat transferred to/from the reservoir whose temperature is $T$.

Comment: @hyportnex  Just because one part of the universe experiences an internally reversible change during a process does not mean that other parts of the universe also experience internally reversible changes.  The definition of an internally reversible change for a system is that, at every stage of the process, the system is never more than slightly removed from being at thermodynamic equilibrium.  This may not be the case for the remainder of the universe during the process.

Comment: sure, but if anywhere the process is irreversibile then $\oint \frac {\delta Q}{T} >0$

Comment: As I said, the process can be carried out "internally reversibly" within the system but not reversibly within the surroundings.  For example, you may be manually (by hand) subjecting a cylinder/piston system to an adiabatic expansion or compression in which it passes through a continuous sequence of thermodynamic equilibrium states, while your body (consisting of your arm, blood vessels, skeleton) is experiencing irreversible change to bring about the compression; the piston/cylinder system is experiencing an "internally reversible" process, while the surroundings (your body) is not.

Comment: Moran et al, Fundamentals of Engineering Thermodynamics, Chapter 5, p 253:  "An *internally reversible process* is one for which there are no irreversibilities within the system.  Irreversibilities may be located within the surroundings however."

Comment: @ChetMiller great example